# nftable filter input blocking host traffic

Tags: debian, networking, nftables

I am attempting to setup linux router on Debian 10 with nftables. I have followed a few tutorials and done some reading which has increased my confusion with my issue. I have 3 interfaces on the router, WAN, management and LAN1, I have the basic setup working as expected but now, I have attempted to preform updates on the server I have found the local traffic is being blocked going out the WAN interface. My nftable.conf is below

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain output {
            type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
            iif WAN ip protocol icmp accept
            iif WAN drop
            iif LAN1 ip protocol icmp accept
            iif LAN1 udp dport {67, 68} accept
            iif LAN1 counter drop
            iif Management accept
    }
    chain forward {
            type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
            iif LAN1 oifname WAN accept
            iif WAN oifname LAN1 ct state related,established accept
    }
}

 table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
    }
    chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            oif WAN masquerade
    }
}
```

I am able to ping ip addresses though the WAN interface due to the icmp rule, but as soon as I introduced the "iif WAN drop" as I am wanting to block all other traffic to the WAN interface, rule I am unable to resolve domain names as the DNS server is accessible though the WAN interface.

From my understanding the output rule should be allowing outbound from the host so do not understand why host traffic is being blocked by the input filter.

with the few tests I have completed form a client node attached to the LAN1 interface there are no restrictions to the though traffic, clients are able to browse though this host.

If anyone can point out my mistake or explain why this has affected host traffic.

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry. Are you talking about DNS queries from the router itself or queries from clients arriving on LAN1? If second case, are the queries destined to an external server, and thus being fowarded, or are they being answered by the router? That is, what is the DNS server being provided to clients via DHCP? I am assuming there is a DHCP server on the router since UDP 67 packets are being accepted on LAN1, right?

Comment: They are dns queries from the host its self. all external hosts are forwarding and responding as expected. more than just DNS queries are being blocked from the host. it seems all traffic generated by the host is being blocked form going out though the WAN interface. I have attempted to access a website using w3m and ip address which also is not completing. I though the output filter was responsable for host traffic so confused why the block rule on the input chain is causing the probem. unless it is blocking the responce?

Comment: Well, yes. The rules are blocking any packets arriving on WAN destined for the router itself (except ICMP packets). If you want the router to be able to establish connections itself, you need a `ct state established,related accept`, just like in the forward chain. I would also add, for good measure, an explicit accept rule for the loopback interface.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira you should write your comment as an answer since it describes the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

The rules in the input chain are droping any packets arriving on WAN destined for the router itself (except ICMP packets). If you want the router itself to be able to establish connections, you need a rule `iff WAN ct state established,related accept`, similar to the one in the forward chain. This rule has to come before `iff WAN drop`. I would also add, for good measure, an explicit accept rule for the loopback interface.